# CoreData ManagedObject and App Model interaction

Tags: ios, json, core-data, dto

I have a set of objects that I use as DTO and they are objects that I create from JSON that I receive from backend.
For example I have object "User" that represent all users in the database. I get them by rest service by JSON and convert it in User object.

All this DTO have the same base class called "BaseDTO".

On the other hand I have represent this objects in Core Data because I have to save it on disk.

My problem is that when I create an entity in CoreData its inherit from `NSManagedObject`.

For this reason I have to create for example "User" object that its DTO and "UserCoreData" that its entity coreData and both has the same fields.

When I want to save an "User" in CoreData I get the "User" object and by a method in "UserCoreData" class create a "UserCoreData" by "User" object fields that I pass to method.

This way is a little cumbersome, and I want to ask you if you can suggest a cleaner way to do this

Answer (score 2):

So what you could do, depending on whatever your DTO base class is doing, is to extract certain functionality of it to protocol and add a default implementation in a protocol extension.

Then your NSManagedObject subclass can adopt this protocol and this way you can use the DTO functionality wherever necessary. If this is not an option, there is no other way than to have duplicate model definitions.

And then it depends on your use case and you have to ask yourself if you really need to use CoreData. 
Just for saving the current data on disk, there are also other options, such as Codable.
CoreData is great if you need to modify objects and query for partial data, and getting notified about changes. But just for persisting whole objects, it is sometimes doing too much.